# How to build dynamic library when running Rust integration tests with Cargo?

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo, dylib, .so

When running integration tests with cargo (currently I run `cargo test --test integration`), how can I also make cargo build the cdylib?

From `Cargo.toml`:

```
[lib]
crate_type = ["cdylib"]
```

The integration tests do not `use` the library (they load the built library dynamically into other processes). Currently when I run the test the library does not get built.